# Why can std::function not accept a deduced type as its template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, types, template-argument-deduction

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<class CharType>
void f1(CharType* str, function<bool(CharType)> fn_filter)
{}

template<class CharType>
void f2(CharType* str, function<bool(char)> fn_filter)
{}

void f3(char* str, char c)
{
    auto fn_filter = [=](char e) -> bool 
    {
        return e == c; 
    };

    f1(str, fn_filter); // error C2784
    f2(str, fn_filter); // OK
}

int main()
{
    f3("ok", 'k');
}

// error C2784: 'void f1(CharType *,std::function<bool(CharType)>)' 
// : could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<bool(CharType)>' 
// from 'f2::<lambda_36be5ecc63077ff97cf3d16d1d5001cb>'
```

My compiler is VC++ 2013.

Why does `f1` not work as expected?

Comment: I know the answer to this, but I can't think of a good way to word it. If nobody else tries, I'll come up with something later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem for the compiler is to decide which of your parameters to use for the type deduction. If you help the compile by breaking the possible deduction from the second parameter and *force* it to use the first, it works as expected:

```
template<typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };

template<class CharType>
void f1(CharType* str, typename identity<function<bool(CharType)>>::type fn_filter)
{}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a98f2d825a77c50a)

Answer (score 9):

The lambda doesn't have type `std::function<bool(char)>`, it is just some callable object with implementation defined type.

It can be *converted* to `std::function<bool(char)>`, but that doesn't help the compiler to deduce the type for the template case. There could for example be lot's of possibilities for `CharType` for which the lambda can be converted to `std::function<bool(CharType)>`.

The compiler tries to match the type of the lambda against the parameter of the template function. The lambda has for example a type like `lambda_t_1234` and the template parameter is `std::function<bool(CharType)>`. The types are unrelated and it's not clear what `CharType` is supposed to be here.

This also isn't special to lambdas or `std::function<>`. The same happens in all such cases:

```
template<typename Char>
void f(const std::basic_string<Char> &str) {
}
```

If you try to call this template function with a `char*` parameter it won't work, because the connection to the template parameter isn't clear.

Comment: Your example is slightly different though, since the OP as an *explicit* `CharType*` as a first parameter and passes a `char*`, so we could reasonably expect `CharType` to be deduced to `char` in the OP's very special case.

Comment: @MSalters: No he isn't. `CharType` is also deduced for the second parameter, it's *not* a non-deducible context. Try passing any `std::function<bool(T)>` for which `T` != `char`. You'll get a deduction mismatch. You can make it a non-deducible context, though, and force the conversion that way.

Comment: @Xeo: Right. You indeed have two deducible contexts, and deduction fails in one context. It's not a case of SFINAE, though, so this failure is fatal.

Comment: Repeat after me: lambdas are not `std::function`, and `std::function` are not lambdas.