# How to auto deduct argument and return type of lambda with std::function?

Tags: c++

This code:

```
template<typename Arg, typename Ret>
Ret fun(std::function<Ret(Arg)> fun){
    Arg x=0;
    return fun(x);
};

auto f=[](int x){return x;};
fun(f);  //compilation failed.
```

doesn't work.  I want to get the argument and return type of lambda in `fun`.

I think the argument type has already known at comile time, why the compilier can't deduct it automaticall?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can std::function not accept a deduced type as its template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673760/why-can-stdfunction-not-accept-a-deduced-type-as-its-template-parameter)

Comment: Adding to the linked duplicate, your simplest solution is to write `auto fun(Fnc&& fun)` and use `std::invoke(std::forward<Fnc>(fun),x)` which will work with any callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the lambda is not an `std::function`, so you're asking the compiler to do a deduction (find the type of `Arg` AND `Ret`) and a convertion i.e. convert the lambda to an `std::function`. The combination causes a conflict.

If you want to still use `std::function` as argument type for `fun`, then the easier thing to do is to make a utility that identifies what `std::function` to cast your callable to, e.g.:

```cpp
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct memfun_type
{
    using type = void;
};

template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct memfun_type<Ret(Class::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using type = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
};

template<typename F>
typename memfun_type<decltype(&std::decay_t<F>::operator())>::type
function_from(F&& func)
{
    return std::forward<F>(func);
}
```

which you'd use as

```
fun(function_from(f)); // Auto-detect <Ret(Args...)> types.
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61e8968096c285ad)

After showing the mechanics of how auto-detection works, note that from C++17 onwards the CTAD feature does this for you. So in newer compilers this also works:

```
fun(std::function(f)); // Again no types specified.
```

Alternatively, you can make your `f` a bit more generic and use just the argument deduction, like:

```
template <class F>
auto fun(F &&fun)
{
    int x=0;
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(fun), x);
};

fun(f); // Call directly with your lambda
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0fc5a0c9f9aead7)

Using c++20 concepts, this version can be restricted to the argument and input function types that you want.

Comment: I need the type of arguments, so the second example is not enough. After some search, I though you first example is the best we can get.

Comment: @kilasuelika The first example is good to understand the mechanics of what the compiler needs to do and why the failure happens. I added a c++17 solution that does the whole thing for you, so if you can afford a "newer" version of c++ it's probably better to use that.

Comment: Yes, the C++ 17 `std::function(f)` is better. Thank you.